# Motoman_driver with dual Motoman Mh5

Tags: ros, motoman-driver, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I have two Motoman mh5 robot, and they are already connected to the same FS100 controller.
I use ROS_Kinetic and MotoRosFS_182.out.
But when I tried to launch motoman_driver, I got some error of it.

I followed these steps:

```
roscore
rosparam load `rospack find motoman_mh5_support`/urdf/dual_motoman_mh5/dual_motoman_mh5.urdf robot_description
rosparam set controller_joint_names "[r1_joint_s, r1_joint_l, r1_joint_u, r1_joint_r, r1_joint_b, r1_joint_t,  r2_joint_s, r2_joint_l, r2_joint_u, r2_joint_r, r2_joint_b, r2_joint_t]"
roslaunch motoman_driver robot_multigroup_interface_streaming_fs100.launch robot_ip:=192.168.0.20
```

In this step

```
roslaunch motoman_driver robot_multigroup_interface_streaming_fs100.launch robot_ip:=192.168.0.20
```

I get the errors below:

```
cyc@cyc-X550JX:~$ roslaunch motoman_driver robot_multigroup_interface_streaming_fs100.launch robot_ip:=192.168.0.20
... logging to /home/cyc/.ros/log/3e360c46-9658-11e9-aed2-9c5c8e1afee7/roslaunch-cyc-X550JX-22607.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://cyc-X550JX:41411/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /robot_ip_address: 192.168.0.20
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.14

NODES
  /
    joint_state (motoman_driver/robot_state_bswap)
    joint_trajectory_action (motoman_driver/motoman_driver_joint_trajectory_action)
    motion_streaming_interface (motoman_driver/motion_streaming_interface_bswap)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

process[joint_state-1]: started with pid [22624]
process[motion_streaming_interface-2]: started with pid [22625]
process[joint_trajectory_action-3]: started with pid [22632]
[ERROR] [1561364152.222744438]: Failed to find topic_list parameter
[ERROR] [1561364152.231102176]: Failed to find topic_list parameter
[ERROR] [1561364152.235351392]: Failed to copy JointData.  Len (12) out of range (0 to 10)
[ERROR] [1561364152.235397456]: Failed to parse position data from JointFeedbackMessage
[ERROR] [1561364152.235424544]: Failed to convert SimpleMessage
[ERROR] [1561364152.235485291]: Failed to copy JointData.  Len (12) out of range (0 to 10)
[ERROR] [1561364152.235505005]: Failed to parse position data from JointFeedbackMessage
[ERROR] [1561364152.235522137]: Failed to convert SimpleMessage
[ERROR] [1561364152.235555953]: Message callback for message type: 2017, not executed
[ERROR] [1561364152.240573440]: Failed to find topic_list parameter
[ERROR] [1561364152.259931804]: Failed to copy JointData.  Len (12) out of range (0 to 10)
[ERROR] [1561364152.259967959]: Failed to parse position data from JointFeedbackMessage
[ERROR] [1561364152.259980652]: Failed to convert SimpleMessage
[ERROR] [1561364152.260358610]: Failed to copy JointData.  Len (12) out of range (0 to 10)
[ERROR] [1561364152.260385853]: Failed to parse position data from JointFeedbackMessage
[ERROR] [1561364152.260411328]: Failed to convert SimpleMessage
```

Does anyone know how to solve it?
Hope you could help me this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/326749/motoman_driver-with-dual-motoman-mh5/) by [A_YIng](https://answers.ros.org/users/40085/a_ying/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2019-06-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you seen the [Creating a Dual-Arm System (Indigo+)](http://wiki.ros.org/motoman_driver/Tutorials/Creating%20a%20Dual-Arm%20System) page? It's not perfect, but it should show you how to setup a configuration file for a multi-group system.

I would also recommend using a `.launch` file instead of starting things manually. That will be much more convenient.

The specific errors you show are basically caused by the fact that the driver is unaware of the configuration of your controller.

---

Edit: partial example (created from memory: I'm away from my computer so I can't test it):

launch file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
  <arg name="robot_ip" default="192.168.0.20" />
  <arg name="controller" default="fs100" />

  <param name="robot_description"
    textfile="$(find motoman_mh5_support)/urdf/dual_motoman_mh5/dual_motoman_mh5.urdf"/>

  <!-- the yaml file could obviously be anywhere -->
  <rosparam command="load" file="$(find motoman_mh5_support)/config/motion_interface.yaml" />

  <include file="$(find motoman_driver)/launch/robot_multigroup_interface_streaming_$(arg controller).launch">
    <arg name="robot_ip" value="$(arg robot_ip)" />
  </include>

  <!-- if you already have one external to this launch file, then don't add this one -->
  <node type="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" name="robot_state_publisher" />

</launch>
```

You may also need a `joint_state_publisher` to gather and merge all the `joint_state` topics that the driver publishes, but I can't check right now (and it also depends on your use-case(s)).

the referenced `motion_interface.yaml`:

```
topic_list:
  - name: r1 # might have to be switched with the 'ns' key
    ns: mh5
    group: 0
    joints: [r1_joint_s, r1_joint_l, r1_joint_u, r1_joint_r, r1_joint_b, r1_joint_t]
  - name: r2 # might have to be switched with the 'ns' key
    ns: mh5
    group: 1
    joints: [r2_joint_s, r2_joint_l, r2_joint_u, r2_joint_r, r2_joint_b, r2_joint_t]
```

You'll obviously have to check whether the `group: 0` and `group: 1` are correct.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [A_YIng](https://answers.ros.org/users/40085/a_ying/) on 2019-06-24**:
Thank you! It works like a charm! Now I can enable my robot servos!

I try to plan a motion with moveit rviz, but I got some error and it doesn't move.
Here is my controllers.yaml file contents in the moveit_config folder:

```
controller_list:
  - name: ""
    action_ns: joint_trajectory_action
    type: FollowJointTrajectory
    joints: [r1_joint_s, r1_joint_l, r1_joint_u, r1_joint_r, r1_joint_b, r1_joint_t,r2_joint_s, r2_joint_l, r2_joint_u, r2_joint_r, r2_joint_b, r2_joint_t]
```

Is it wrong?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-24**:
Well, yes.

The groups defined in the `topic_list` parameter must be matched by the configuration of MoveIt.

The `topic_lists` I suggested does not have a single group with all joints. It has two groups, each with the joints of the respective robot. You'll have to update MoveIt's configuration to match.

**Comment by [A_YIng](https://answers.ros.org/users/40085/a_ying/) on 2019-06-24**:
After I modified it, I got the same error.

```
controller_list:
  - name: mh5/r1
    action_ns: joint_trajectory_action
    type: FollowJointTrajectory
    joints: [r1_joint_s, r1_joint_l, r1_joint_u, r1_joint_r, r1_joint_b, r1_joint_t]
  - name: mh5/r2
    action_ns: joint_trajectory_action
    type: FollowJointTrajectory
    joints: [r2_joint_s, r2_joint_l, r2_joint_u, r2_joint_r, r2_joint_b, r2_joint_t]
```

I tried to surveyed some repos which like these on github, but still  can't find the similar one.
By the way, should I open a new issue for this?